# Access 2016 - combine data from multiples columns in one table in to one column to be searched

Tags: microsoft-access, combine

My database contains all the engineering changes that are carried out and produces a report for the operator to print with all necessary data on.
Each row in the database is a new entry, there can be no duplicate engineering change numbers so I am using the autonumber function.

In the database, there are 10 columns for the operator to list any drawings or documents that they have changed during the engineering change. There is then another 10 for the issue numbers and a further 10 for the titles.

I want to be able to provide a search function for the operator to look up drawings and documents, but what they would see is just 3 columns, the drawing or document number, issue number and title.

I am not great at VBA but can get by with guidance, I would say I am in the dangerous category, too much knowledge for break it but not enough to work it out myself.

I have added a screenshot of the table area drawing and document list that I am talking about:

[image: table area drawing and document list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a thread on another forum that addresses what you want https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=188663

The search form has more capabilities than what you want to do, but the search using a text box to search multiple fields (and multiple tables) is addressed. There is also a sample database for download.

On a simpler note, I made a simple query, search form with a text box for the search string you want to look for. You enter the text, click button, and the query runs.

Here is the query: SELECT tblSamples.SampleID, tblSamples.Sample, tblSamples.Data, tblSamples.Drawing, tblSamples.Modification FROM tblSamples WHERE (((tblSamples.Sample) Like "" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![txtSearch] & "")) OR (((tblSamples.Data) Like "" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![txtSearch] & "")) OR (((tblSamples.Drawing) Like "" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![txtSearch] & "")) OR (((tblSamples.Modification) Like "" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![txtSearch] & ""));

This is based on my sample table (tblSamples) with four fields, search form (frmSearch), that has a button that runs the query

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try in the next day or two.

Answer (score 0):

There are various examples out there for what you want to do. You would only have to make a query with your desired fields to be searched, make a form with that query as the record source.
Then add text boxes where people would type the search words they are looking for, for each field. Here is an excellent, easily understood tutorial I have used: https://www.599cd.com/tips/access/multi-field-search-form-like/

Comment: Here is another excellent example of a search form, this one is more involved, using VB code. But he does offer a sample database and allows you to use his code in your own database: http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: They both look really good and I will tag them if they are needed in future, however they do not quite answer what I am after. I want to have just one search box for title etc, but I have 10 fields where title could be, so I need to merge those 10 fields somehow so that in the search function there is only one box for title that you type in.

Comment: Ok, I will look around some more. I understand what you want to accomplish now that you restated it. It sounds possible. I may have seen such an idea on my various bookmarked Access help sites I visit.